# Unable to load a required virtual machine component and it's not KB3045999 fault

Tags: windows-7, windows, virtualization

This is known issue that is caused by KB3045999:

> The application was unable to load a required virtual machine
>   component.  Please contact the publisher of this application for more
>   information.

However even despite uninstalling this security update, the issue returned with one of other recent security updates.

Does anyone know which one it might have been (past 2 months I guess)? Is there anyway to work around this problem apart from uninstalling another security update?

I have some legacy apps that I know I won't get updates for them but I need them to run occasionally.

[image]

Comment: one person suggested  KB3022345 also. If you have a backup , you could just try it?

Answer (score 0):

Usually such error is caused by KB3022345, KB3045999 or KB3068708. These updates can easily be uninstalled.

Unfortunately some new update arrived. I've found information that this new update is KB3020370 that cannot be uninstalled. In this case there is no workaround without reinstalling Windows and blocking such update.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it seems like a new updates comes along every few months that causes me the "required virtual machine component" error with some programs. 
So far, these are all the updates I've removed and hidden to deal with the error(note that they all have KB before the number) - 3045999, 3060716, 3071756, 3088195, 3101746

Answer (score -2):

For your first question

> Does anyone know which one it might have been (past 2 months I guess)?

The 2 updates I know that give problems with PostBuild are KB3045999 and KB3022345

For your second question

> Is there anyway to work around this problem apart from uninstalling another security update?

I haven't find a workaround, uninstalling the updates was the only solution.

Comment: @Ramhound - This answer is for exactly this problem. I was trying to run Xenocode Postbuild 2009 on a VM that have been updated but I got the same error message as SiliconMind. I had to remove update KB3045999 and KB3022345 in order to get it working.